# Hadoop FS getFileStatus() modification time is 0 for directories

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I am using the [getFileStatus(Path p) method of hadoop fs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#getFileStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) as following. I use the Java library in Scala. Whenever I call the method for a directory path I get modification time as 0 even though a direct child of the directory has been edited recently.

```
val rawStatus = fs.getFileStatus(path)
```

There isn't any problem calling the method for files. I am getting the correct timestamps for those.

I have tried testing this with multiple different folders on different environments (Azure and AWS). What could be the reason for this? Is this modification time value expected?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:I was wrong about Azure. I can get proper timestamps for Azure directories. This makes me think HDFS doesn't fully work with AWS S3 filesystem since they don't have inodes. Can someone confirm, elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is confirmed to be a S3 specific behaviour. Likely due to the fact that S3 does not have a "real" hierarchy structure. It is a flat storage with directories only being pointers to other files/directories.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).